# Login page not redirecting after login in firefox 5

Tags: firefox-5

I'm writing an application that has a login page. The application is redirecting to the login page just fine, and when I click 'Log In', the user gets authenticated just fine. The last action of the log button postback method is to redirect the user to the page they requested.

However, in firefox 5, it simply refreshes the page. I've run fiddler against it and confirmed that a 302 request to redirect is in fact being sent to the browser. But it's like the browser isn't honoring it. It just shows me the log in page again.

Any ideas?

Comment: So, I think I've figured out that the issue the following: Firefox 5 caches redirects. So when I get redirected to the login page, that get cached, and when I pass login and try to redirect to the original page, firefox sends me to the cached location, ie, the login page. So how do you tell the browser not to cache 301 and 302 responses?

Comment: So if anyone knows a better way to do this, feel free to post it, but the way I finally get it working was to add the following right before I returned the Redirect action:

    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);

This way firefox 5 can't cache the 302 redirect to the login page, so when you attempt to redirect to the original url, it actually sends you there. I'll post this as the answer as soon as I can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if anyone knows a better way to do this, feel free to post it, but the way I finally get it working was to add the following right before I returned the Redirect action:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
```

This way firefox 5 can't cache the 302 redirect to the login page, so when you attempt to redirect to the original url, it actually sends you there.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct answer. I just had the same problem as well and solved it by adding cache control headers on 301/302 redirects. Seems like firefox 5 is more strict on the existence of these headers.